# Pandas dataframe convert_object with a certain columns to be type fixed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeconverter

Can someone provide a quick/best solution to use the dataframe `convert_objects` method with `convert_numeric=True` but excluding certain columns whose types are known?

My raw data has 50+ columns of mixed type, I like to use the convenient `convert_objects` method to convert columns to the right type. It works like charm until values eg. `'XBGH0102'` show up in str type column. The column then been converted to float64 type and filled with NaN.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
columns = [ list_of_columns .... ]
frame_to_save = df[df.columns.difference(columns)]
frame_to_process = df[columns]

result = pd.concat([ frame_to_save,
                     frame_to_process.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)],
                   axis=1).reindex(df.columns)
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, Your answer gives an idea.